# Django inbuilt Auth not logging me in despite successfully registering the user

Tags: django, django-authentication

i would like to login after registering a user that is saved using my customuser model that exends abstractuser.
after registering the user, i redirect them to the login page.
and when i try to login the user with the credentials that is just created, it will say "__ all __
Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." when i print form.errors
i am not sure why the backends is throwing this error, i have tried looking into the authenticationform that i extended as well as the save and create_user.
just wondering too; is it better if i created a userprofile model instead of extending the default django user model?
here is my models.py

```py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):
        print('in customusermanager create_user')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(gettext_lazy('You must provide a valid email address'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser %s must be assigned to is_staff=True' % (username))
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser %s must be assigned to is_superuser=True' % (username))
        
        return self.create_user(email, username, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields)
        
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(gettext_lazy('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    about = models.TextField(gettext_lazy('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False) # user account will not be active upon creation. TODO: add sending email to user to activate then can login
    is_agency = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and here is my forms.py

```py
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_agency')
    
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Your email',
        'class': 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
    }))

    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Your username',
        'class': 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
    })) 

    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Your first name',
        'class': 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
    })) 

    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': 'Your last name',
        'class': 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
    })) 

    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': '••••••••',
        'class': 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
    }))

    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'placeholder': '••••••••',
        'class': 'bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500'
    }))
    
    is_agency = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
        'id': 'is_agency',
        'class': 'w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-primary-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800'
    }))

    def save(self):
        self.clean()
        user = self.Meta.model(
            username = self.cleaned_data['username'], 
            email = self.cleaned_data['email'], 
            password = self.cleaned_data['password2'], 
        )
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

my views.py

```py
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/listing/login/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'listing/registration.html', {'form':form})

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        print(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'listing/login.html', {'form': form})
```

my registration.html

```html
<form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Email</label>
        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.email.errors }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="username" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Username</label>
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="first_name" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">First Name</label>
        {{ form.first_name }}
        {{ form.first_name.errors }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="last_name" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Last Name</label>
        {{ form.last_name }}
        {{ form.last_name.errors }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Password</label>
        {{ form.password1 }}
        {{ form.password1.errors }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="confirm_password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Confirm password</label>
        {{ form.password2 }}
        {{ form.password2.errors }}
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-start">

        <div class="flex items-center h-5">
            {{ form.is_agency }} 
        </div>
        <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
            <label for="is_agency" class="font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300">Are you an Employment Agent?</label>
        </div>
        {{ form.errors }}
        <!--<div class="flex items-center h-5">
            <input id="terms" aria-describedby="terms" type="checkbox" class="w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-primary-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
            <label for="terms" class="font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300">I accept the <a class="font-medium text-primary-600 hover:underline dark:text-primary-500" href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
        </div>-->
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="w-full text-white bg-primary-600 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">Create an account</button>
    <p class="text-sm font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Already have an account? 
        <a href="# " class="font-medium text-primary-600 hover:underline dark:text-primary-500">Login here</a>
    </p>
</form>
```